# FactoryGirl with associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, factory-bot

I have 2 models, Product and Category.
Product has `category_id` attribute. So, Product belongs to Category, and Category has many Products.

```
<!-- language: rb -->
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :category
  validates :category, presence: true
end

class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :products
end
```

How can I define factories (FactoryGirl rails) for both models? Especially interesting how to do this for Product model.

Comment: It may help others if you fix the typo in the question title ("associations") since that's a common search term.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two scenarios that you might want to use.

**If you don't need a specific Category associated with the Product:**

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :category do
    # category fields
  end
  factory :product do
    # other product fields here
    category
  end
end
```

Then you can `create(:product)`, and it will get a **new** Category assigned to it when it's created.

**If you need to re-use a known Category with the product:**

In this case, you need to create the objects explicitly.  You can use the same factories above, but create them like this:

```
category = create(:category)
product = create(:product, category: category)
```

This way you'll be able to re-use the category for multiple products, or manipulate the two separately.

Comment: I dont want to allow Product to have no category, so I dont make category_id writable. But then I have a warning DEPRECATION WARNING: You're trying to create an attribute `category_id'. Writing arbitrary attributes on a model is deprecated.

Comment: You can enforce that with a validation that requires a Category to be present and exist.  If you want to restrict changes to a Category after creation, that's best handled at the controller level.

Comment: I added validates :category, presence: true, but I still have warnings.

Comment: You also need `attr_accessible :category_id` in your Product model.

Comment: I added attr_accessible :category_id too, but warning still appear. http://pastebin.com/a7wtM5f2

Answer (score 1):

If you use Mongodb, you can embed data inside your Factory. For example :

```
factory :category do
  name "My Category"
  product {{
    "name" => "My product",
    "price" => "12"
  }}
end
```

In this case, don't forget to `accepts_nested_attributes_for :products` inside your `Categories` model.